# Tool to Analyze SQL Server performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

Is there any 3rd party tool which works like another layer on top of SQL Server, which can analyze the behaviour of the database and make recommendations based on that?

Thanks

Comment: Yes they're called database administrators and you can hire them.

Comment: Though most DBA's are not tools...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qure from DBSophic does a great job at what you describe. You can also bundle it with our tools (for a much more cost effective offering), SQL Sentry Event Manager and Performance Advisor, which provide general around the clock performance monitoring and alerting (these tools are mostly for use by DBAs, and don't provide automatic optimizations the way Qure can).

http://www.dbsophic.com/

http://www.sqlsentry.net/

https://sqlblog.org/2011/04/21/using-qure-workload-optimizer-for-sql-sentry

Answer (score 4):

*Late answer but can be helpful to other readers, I hope*

In addition the solutions already mentioned, I can recommend [ApexSQL Monitor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_monitor.aspx)
This tool will allow you to define custom metrics you want to track (in addition to numerous predefined metrics for the System, SQL Server and Database).

ApexSQL Monitor can also show the slowest queries executing on the SQL Server. It stores individual wait statistics for the single query, and by analyzing waits, you can detect the reasons of slow performing queries. It can also show the query execution plan at the time of execution, which will provide you even more info about slow executing queries.

Answer (score 3):

If its more generic monitoring your after, such as current load, flagging jobs that take longer than usual etc, there are some pretty decent 3rd party tools, Red Gates SQL Monitor is pretty cool, demo here: http://monitor.red-gate.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Profiler (not 3rd party) to see queries/procedures/etc and how slow/heavy they are. It won't give you any recommendations but you can take further actions once you see where the problems lie.

Comment: You can also use the results of the profiler trace as input to the  Database Engine Tuning Advisor (DTA, Also not third party) to make recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of a DBA SQL Server ships with a [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494.aspx).

> ... After analyzing a workload, Database Engine Tuning Advisor can
>   recommend that you add, remove, or modify physical design structures
>   in your databases. The advisor can also recommend ...